# How do I convert an HttpStatusCodeResult to a JsonResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

- I have an MVC action method of type ActionResult.
- I'm currently returning an HttpStatusCodeResult
- this is giving me a JSON error at the consuming JQuery AJAX call
- how can I wrap this into a JSON object that is an ActionResult using json.net? I want to see if this fixes the JSON error

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is supposed to be reserved about questions about the *pattern*; there is a specific tag for the ASP.NET implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Directly specify JSON:

```
return Json(new { yourvariablename = HttpStatusCodeResult });
```

If you need to return the view also:

```
var obj = new {
          yourvariablename = HttpStatusCodeResult
        };
return View(Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
```

or if it is partial view:

```
var obj = new {
          yourvariablename = HttpStatusCodeResult
        };
return PartialView((Object)JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```